# How can I add the "Play sounds for notifications" option for my app in macOS "Notifications & Focus" settings?

Tags: swift, macos, unusernotificationcenter, macos-monterey

My app successfully handles notifications with the following blocks of code:

```swift
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound]) { _, _ in }
```

and:

```swift
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    return completionHandler([.alert, .sound])
}
```

and:

```swift
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings { (settings) in
    if settings.authorizationStatus == .authorized {
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        let id = "MB"
        let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: DateComponents(calendar: Calendar.current), repeats: false)
        
        if self.appModel.isNotifyingOnBreak {
            content.title = "A message:"
            content.body = self.appModel.notificationContent
        }

        content.sound = .default
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: id, content: content, trigger: trigger)
        
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request)
    }
}
```

When I look at my apps in the macOS "Notifications & Focus" settings, I can see my app in the left sidebar with "Sounds, Alerts". However, in the right section, there is no option to toggle the notification sound.

How can I add the "Play sounds for notifications" option, like there is for the "Messages" app and many other apps?

Comment: What happens if you add `.badge` to the options?

Comment: Thanks! That works   Isn't that a bit strange? I'm not even using badges - in fact, my app is a menu bar app (no dock icon).

Comment: It looks like a bug to me.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need `.badge` for it to work (Thanks Willeke for pointing that out). I agree it's weird, and I don't really understand how it works either.

I also found another article on Swift notifications, maybe this might help.

https://betterprogramming.pub/scheduling-notifications-and-badges-in-swiftui-9edf8574b893

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to first authroize and register for the remote notification

```
// modoify & adapt as needed
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: options) { granted, _ in
    guard granted else { return }
    // your custom code        ...

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        NSApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }
}

// Then modify the remote notification like so
NSApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications(matching: [.alert, .sound, .badge])
```